# I am trying to use the upper function for the input

Tags: python, input

I am trying to make the input the user enters capital but it only makes the question capital

```
name = input("Please enter your name ".upper())
```

Comment: Yes, you need to call it on the result, not on the argument.

Comment: can you showme how i should do that

Comment: `name = input("Please enter your name ").upper()`

Answer (score 2):

You are uppercasing the *prompt*, the string value passed to `input()`. You need to uppercase the *result*, the value returned by the function:

```
name = input("Please enter your name ").upper()
```

Note the placement of the closing parentheses there.

You could separate out the `input()` call from the uppercasing:

```
name = input("Please enter your name ")
name = name.upper()
```

if that makes it clearer for you.

In essence, your attempt did this instead:

```
prompt = "Please enter your name "
prompt = prompt.upper()
name = input(prompt)
```

which is why you see `PLEASE ENTER YOUR NAME` on your screen when you run your code.